# How to make a textbox which should accept only angular-typeahead list values and clear the content that is not in the typeahead list?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

For Example, I have a form with a textfield which gives typeahead lists to select values. If a user enters something that is not in the typeahead list, i should clear that content that is not in typeahead list. How to achieve it ?????

Answer (score 1):

If you use the typeahead from bootstrap library : http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

And underscoreJs : http://underscorejs.org/

You can resolve your problem by using the function "$watch" from $scope variable in your controller.

Which allows you to check any changement in a variable in scope, if the new value of your input does not exist in your array of values, you put an empty string in your input variable.

I made an example : http://plnkr.co/edit/cp9SLKhLYowIwFXVImAK?p=preview
(it's case sensitive)

```
$scope.$watch('selected', function(newVal, oldVal){
    var newValPotentiallyExist= _.any($scope.states, function(state){
        return state.indexOf(newVal) != -1;
    });
    if(!newValPotentiallyExist){
       $scope.selected = '';
    }
});
```

Comment: +1 for giving me a answer. But why i can't type more than 2 characters in a text field.?? For example , if i want to type " albania" and i can type only al - after that its get cleared.

Comment: It's because it's case sensitive.
Change :
"return state.indexOf(newVal) != -1;"
 by
"return state.toLowerCase().indexOf(newVal.toLowerCase()) != -1;"